# Would it be possible to use SANSA-RDF & SANSA-Query in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdf, turtle-rdf, sansa

I am planning to use SANSA-RDF for reading turtle RDF/XML files into Spark and query using SANSA-Query library. Would it be possible to develop PySpark (python) code using theses libraries? Are there any PySpark (python) examples?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I really appreciate if any one can share their suggestions & thoughts...